# How to restart a loop on exception

Tags: python, loops

I have this code:

```
for i in range(n):
    for v in range (m): 
        # code
        try:
            # more code
        except IndexError:
            os.system('python "Example.py"')
```

`os.system('python "Example.py"')` allows me to reinitialize the entire code, but what I really want to do is to go back right before the `for v in range(m):` part and start that loop again.
How can I do this? Is there any other way to do that instead of adding a function? If not, how can I code that function?

Comment: `os.system('python "Example.py"')` nooo. don't do that. In any case, it's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: do you want to include the `for v in range(m)`? Do you want to restart before or after ?

Comment: This looks like an X-Y issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why i should not use that?

Comment: @Shazers I want to restart the code before `for v in range(m)`

Comment: How is restarting the code going to avoid the issue the second time and becoming an endless loop?

Comment: @AnnZen what? it is marked, just below this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for i in range(n):
    v=0
    while (v < m): 
        # code
        try:
            # more code
        except IndexError:
            v-=1
        v+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i can't see that this code will restart my code from `for v in range(m)` but extending it

Comment: Ah then instead of `v-=1` take `v=0`

Comment: Or even better `v=-1` then you will literally restart the loop for `v`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
restart = True

for i in range(n):

    while restart:

        for v in range (m): 
            # code
            try:
                # more code
                restart = False
            except IndexError:
                # more code
```

Comment: `while restart = True: [...] SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It should have just been `while restart:`, restart is a boolean, comparing it to `True` would do nothing but produce the same boolean. Also, have a look at the first, most upvoted comment on the question.

Comment: It is not at all a recommended thing to do, so it would be better to avoid including it in answers, as it could tend to give the impression to less experienced users that it is good practice - even though that's what the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```py
for i in range(n):
    getting_errors = True
    while x:
        for v in range(m):
            try:
                #code
            except Exception:
                #code
                break
            else:
                getting_errors = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly neater than Gzegzor's example.

```
for i in range(n):
    v=0
    while (v < m): 
        # code
        try:
            # more code
        except IndexError:
            continue
        v += 1
```